# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: select Selection tool for text and images by default

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, user-experience, usability

A simple question: how to select "Selection tool for text and images" by default?

Now the default is "Click to pan around the document":

[image]

Need to change that.

Here are some current settings:

[image]

What needs to be changed?

Tool version:

[image]

Comment: Can't you do with selecting "Make hand tool select text & images" ? It's not exactly the same, but useful for most situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by re-installing (again) the app.

Version:

[image]

After opening a document the "Selection tool" is enabled:

[image]

Expected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think anything needs to be changed.

Both tools are separately selectable and neither is default.

Click directly on top of the Arrow and you get the selection tool and can use that. Click directly on top of the Pan (hand) and you get Click and pan around with the Pan tool.

So there is no default here and you can select what you specifically need.

[image: Adobe toolbar]

Comment: No, I see that the default settings exist: each time Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is opened the "Click to pan around the document" is selected regardless the fact that Adobe Acrobat Reader DC was closed with "Selection tool for text and images" being selected. Hence, there is a need to change the default settings. How?

Comment: Try re-installing Adobe and restarting. There is no default on my installations. Just pick the tool you want.

Comment: I re-installed the app. The problem still persists. The Pan (hand) tool is selected (enabled) each time I open the app. Any help/ideas? I use the latest version 22.001.20085.

Comment: And now there is a [new problem](https://superuser.com/q/1713931/295913).