# Cannot install Adobe Acrobat Reader DC due to "Old/New Acrobat version already installed"

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, user-experience

Trying to solve [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1681392/adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-select-selection-tool-for-text-and-images-by-default), I decided to (again) re-install Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

As usual I removed it via "Add or remove programs".

All went fine.

But then I cannot install the new one due to "Old/New Acrobat version already installed":

[image]

So, I rebooted the machine. The same message.

Why it says that the "Old/New Acrobat version already installed" if it was removed?

If you click "Finish" there is:

[image]

But it is *not installed*.

How to fix?

---

UPD. Somehow it finally installed. I did nothing special. Here is the version:

[image]

UPD2. Hm. It seems that it is not installed (because the version is contains "2019"), but that there is *another* version (2019) installed on the machine. Investigating...

Comment: See if this Adobe app helps you.       https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Labs/cleaner.html